# Why is this canvas code so slow?

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

I have short code, that draws circles (orbits) dots (satellites) on these orbits. Satellites are moving around orbits. In fact code isn't mine, but I was asked to solve the problem.

According to profiler in chrome and firefox, function `drawSatellite` eats 50%-100% cpu and I would like to know why.

Canvas is same big as your window (1920x1080). There are around 160 orbits (increasing with time page is online).

This is `drawSatellite`:

```
OrbitBackground.prototype.drawSatellite = function(ctx, satellite) {
  ctx.fillStyle = satellite.satellite.fill;
  ctx.beginPath();

  if (++satellite.satellite.angularPosition == 360)
    satellite.satellite.angularPosition = 0;

  // 1 FPS = 60 calls => 180 / 6 (6-times faster @ 60 FPS) = 30
  var radians = satellite.satellite.angularPosition * Math.PI / 30 / satellite.rps;

  if (satellite.backward)
    radians = -radians;

  ctx.arc(
      satellite.satellite.x + satellite.orbit.radius * Math.cos(radians),
      satellite.satellite.y + satellite.orbit.radius * Math.sin(radians),
      satellite.satellite.radius,
      0,
      Math.PI*2,
      true
  );
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
};
```

Function that calls it:

```
OrbitBackground.prototype.drawFrame = function() {
  if (this.running)
    requestAnimationFrame(this.drawFrame.bind(this));

  this.dynamicStageCtx.clearRect(0, 0, this.pageWidth, this.pageHeight);

  for (var i=0; i < this.orbits.length; i++) {
    this.drawSatellite(this.dynamicStageCtx, this.orbits[i]);
  }
};
```

Comment: I think problem could be, that we work with canvas as 2D context and we use javascript functions instead of shaders, so operations could be just too heavy, because cpu is not able to call all those javascript functions for each frame? But it is just a theory...

Comment: Are your FPS too low? High CPU consumption not always means code is slow or not optimal. The main thing you should care is your draw method runs faster than (1000/targetFPS) ms

Comment: In chrome fps is ok, in firefox fps is very low and sometimes browser dies. On embed systems fps is ultra low.

Comment: Code looks pretty simple and clear. I can only suggest to comment your code line by line to find what particular calculation is too heavy. However I don't see a way to optimize it. According to some "tips&tricks" you can omit .closePath() call if your primitive is closed (circles are closed indeed). Also you can draw squares instead of dots if your "satellites" is small enough.

Comment: 1) caching : satellite.satellite can be cached to avoid 6 access, and satellite.orbit.radius can be cached also. 2) What is the fill ? it is good for performances to normalize the fill : after creating the fill, do ctx.fillStyle = myFill; then myFill = ctx.fillStyle; so fill is at the exact right format. 3) try with fillRect to see if the circle draw is not the bottleneck. 4) Notice that both FF and Ch have canvas debugging/profiling tools.

Comment: hmm, I tried 2 samples. [this one seems to run faster in FF than Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/7tTQ3/). [This one is faster in Chrome than FF](http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/z2BbK/) at least on my machine

Answer (score 4):

You're doing this:

```
Loop:
    set fill style
    begin path
    make path
    end path
    fill
```

You would be much faster doing this:

```
set fill style (just once, before loop)
begin path (just one path, with loop-number of subpaths)
Loop:
    moveTo (start of subpath)
    make path
    close path
fill (just once, after loop)
```

But that requires the fill style to be the same on every satellite. If there are only a few colors, you could try to bunch them by their colors.

Note also that calcluating cosine and sine are slow (all trig functions and square root calls are slow), and if you can avoid their use you will be better off.

The size (pixel count) of your canvas also matters. Consider making the canvas half-size or quarter-size (960x540 or 480x270) and scaling it up with CSS.

Comment: Thx for good advice. Canvas cant be smaller, cause it should be background of the page, so it depends on client screen. Indeed I have few colors so I will try to bunch them.

Comment: The canvas can be smaller and then scaled up with CSS to be double or triple its size, but this takes a loss of fidelity

Answer (score 3):

**Might be a problem:**

I don't see a ctx.beginPath before your ctx.arc command.

Without ctx.beginPath all your previous arcs are being redrawn along with your current arc.

**A small optimization**

Assign Math.PI*2 to a variable since it's used very often

```
var PI2=Math.PI*2;
```

**How to eliminate the slowest part of your code ( Math.cos and Math.sin ).**

Since your nodes are going in repeating orbits, you can precalculate all the untranslated [x,y] for a complete orbit.

```
var statellite.orbitTrig=[];

for(var i=0;i<360;i++){
    var radians=PI2/360*i;
    var x=satellite.orbit.radius * Math.cos(radians)
    var y=satellite.orbit.radius * Math.sin(radians)
    satellite.orbitTrig.push({x:x,y:y});
}
```

Then you can refer to the precalculated values in your animation loop.

```
var trig=satellite.orbitTrig[satellite.satellite.angularPosition];
var x=satellite.satellite.x + trig.x;
var y=satellite.satellite.y + trig.y;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x,y,satellite.satellite.radius,0,PI2);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```